# Splitting string based on last occurance of , and _

Tags: javascript, string, associative-array

I have a string that looks like APP1_ENV1,ENV2,ENV3,APP2_ENV4,ENV5,APP3_ENV1 How to split this string so that i get the associative array like app's with its following env's? 
Example output- APP1[ENV1,ENV2,ENV3],APP2[ENV4,ENV5],APP3[ENV1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
input.replace(/([^,_]+)_((?:[^,_]+,)*?[^,_]+)(?=$|,[^,_]+_)/g, "$1[$2]")
```

```
APP1_ENV1,ENV2,ENV3,APP2_ENV4,ENV5,APP3_ENV1
=> APP1[ENV1,ENV2,ENV3],APP2[ENV4,ENV5],APP3[ENV1]
APP1_ENV1,ENV2,ENV3,TREND2_ENV4,ENV5,JADE3_ENV1
=> APP1[ENV1,ENV2,ENV3],TREND2[ENV4,ENV5],JADE3[ENV1]
```

For actual parsing, I'd recommend

```
input.split(/,(?=[^,_]+_)/g).reduce(function(o, str) {
    var parts = str.split("_");
    o[parts[0]] = parts[1].split(",");
    return o;
}, {});
```

```
APP1_ENV1,ENV2,ENV3,APP2_ENV4,ENV5,APP3_ENV1
=> {"APP1":["ENV1","ENV2","ENV3"],"APP2":["ENV4","ENV5"],"APP3":["ENV1"]}
APP1_ENV1,ENV2,ENV3,TREND2_ENV4,ENV5,JADE3_ENV1
=> {"APP1":["ENV1","ENV2","ENV3"],"TREND2":["ENV4","ENV5"],"JADE3":["ENV1"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "APP1_ENV1,ENV2,ENV3,APP2_ENV4,ENV5,APP3_ENV1";
var obj = {};
for(var i=1;i<str.split("APP").length;i++){
   var cont = str.split("APP")[i].slice(0,-1);
   obj["APP"+cont.split("_")[0]]=cont.split("_")[1].split(",")
}
```

Now `obj` contains

```
{"APP1":["ENV1","ENV2","ENV3"],"APP2":["ENV4","ENV5"],"APP3":["ENV"]}
```

As per your requirement.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj);
// "{"APP1":["ENV1","ENV2","ENV3"],"APP2":["ENV4","ENV5"],"APP3":["ENV"]}"`

Comment: Thanks @nicael but incase if my APP has some random string like APP1_ENV1,ENV2,ENV3,TREND2_ENV4,ENV5,JADE3_ENV1